# NetBeans third party javadoc adding problem

Tags: netbeans, javadoc, zxing

I'm trying to add zxing java doc.
I've tried different approaches:
1)  Java Platforms > Javadoc, rather than Tools > Libraries > Javadoc
2)  * Go to Project Properties > Libraries dialog
    * On "Compile" tab press the "Add JAR/Folder" button and locate your library
    * On "Compile" tab press the "Edit" button with your library selected
    * Add javadoc path

I tried different paths:
a) "javadoc" folder, containing index.html
b) "docs" folder, containing "javadocs" folder
c) zip file, containing "docs" folder

But neither of that helped me - I always receive 
"Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or you have not added specified Javadoc in the Java Platform Manager or the Library Manager."

Comment: None of the answers seem to help. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

To add a javadoc of a third party library first you have to create a library bundle inside Netbeans.
Go to `Library Manager (Tools > Libraries)` window and create a `New Library`. You will have to add necessary jar files manually under `Library Classpath` tab.

Then switch to `Javadoc` tab and give the path to your javadoc zip file.
Click `OK` and Netbeans will display the documentation straight away.

Answer (score 0):

you should attach zip file, containing index.html and hierarchy of folders which represent your classes. Don't make some docs folders yourself.